# Diamond operator ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the difference between

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
```

Are the diamond operator when I create a new ArrayList necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first statement is clear. The second generates compilation warning.

Diamond iperator was introduced to java 1.7. Starting from java 1.5 you had to write

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

i.e. declare the generic type both on the left and right sides of the assignment. Since generic types may be more complex than just `Integer` it was annoying to copy exactly the same definition twice, so they added this cool feature to compiler: you just have to say: "this class is generic, use the generic type from the left side of the assignment" by using `<>` marker.

BTW the last comment. Please avoid using concrete classes in the left side of assignments and method definitions. 
The following is much better:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

or even

```
Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

or often even

```
Iterable<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: very informative answer but could you please explain or provide links where to read about this statement: `Please avoid using concrete classes in the left side of assignments and method definitions. The following is much better:...` please why, thank you

Answer (score 1):

A rather advanced topic for Java is called *Generics* and that is the explanation for all the <> symbols.

In essence, you should always write

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Because it is shorthand for

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And you need both type arguments (the  bit) to match otherwise the compiler will give you a warning.

Writing:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
```

Creates an ArrayList that can hold any type, and when you try to convert it into an `ArrayList<Integer>` the compiler will throw a warning.

EDIT:

Here is a in-depth guide on what generics are for and how they work. I'm not sure if you're at the level to understand them fully yet, but it's worth a try.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 0):

First is the parameterized generic object of `ArrayList`, referenced by a parameterized generic reference.

Second is non-parameterized non-generic object of `ArrayList`, referenced by a parameterized generic reference.

No, although the diamond operators are not necessary when you create an `ArrayList`, it is highly recommended to avoid `ClassCastException` or some other `RuntimeException` later on.